# Application configuration versioning

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to use SVN for storing a significant quantity of configuration files in multiple directories within a tree, and also in multiple directories on the drive, and hopefully on different machines also.

Before it became quite so complicated (multiple directories off the drive and multiple machines, I was simply going to add the root directory of the application, exclude all the files/dirs. I wasn't interested in.

Now however I really need to find a way of version across all of these locations so I can record a version number for everything.  This means I can create a branch for changes, when everything is completed and tested, then simply update on the live environment, and if anything is wrong roll back to the previous version.

Regards

Tom

Comment: Why don't you simply use the svn revision as version number?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I would be using the SVN rev number.  But I'd ideally have a rev number that covers the state across all the config files in all dirs etc. so that would be the rev number that appears at the trunk level.

Comment: Please note that the revision number of a svn repository is always repository wide. There simply are no revision numbers to single files or directories in svn. This totally makes sense: svn is simply a file system with an additional time axis: the revision number.

Comment: My question here is not about he revision number.  What I am trying to discover is whether there is anyway that I can create a virtual folder under the trunk folder that will contain 3 further folders from different locations across 2 servers.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read that from your question above. This appears to be some completely separated question. Above you wrote: "so I can record a version number for everything". Now you say this is _not_ about a version number. Hm. I am out, sorry.